# const set of Char and Pascal Script Unit Importer

Tags: delphi, freepascal, pascalscript

I'm running the Pascal Script Unit Importer on a unit, but get this error:

"Expecting token '=' but token 'of' found. Previous tokens: 'WORDDELIMITERS: set of'"

Here is the constant that triggers the error:

```
const
  WordDelimiters: set of Char = [#0..#255] - ['a'..'z','A'..'Z','1'..'9','0'];
```

The constant WordDelimiters is part of a third party library. Is there a way to rewrite something so Unit Importer can work with the unit?

A test shows that set of char is supported:

```
type
  TWordDelimiters = set of Char;
```

The unit importer result:

```
procedure SIRegister_MyTestUnit(CL: TPSPascalCompiler);
begin
  CL.AddTypeS('TWordDelimiters', 'set of Char');
end;
```

But the constant set of char below doesn't work, there is complaint on the '..' double dots:

```
const
  MyChars = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'];
```

Skipping the double dots and typing all chars manually works, but isn't there another way?

```
const
  MyChars = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
```

Comment: I suppose the answer depends on whether Pascal Script supports sets of Char. I'd find that out before trying to translate one into that language.

Comment: I think so, added a test to the question..

Comment: I just added it. Seems like it's a certain syntax the unit importer doesn't like?

Comment: Your update shows that you can define a set type, but not a constant using `set of`. The error clearly states that `of` is not supported in that context.

Comment: Right. Now as a workaround I am using routines that are more compatible with PascalScript.